# Laravel storing array using implode to DB not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have a few problems with my code. I can't get the variable `status` value outside the For statement. I tried to echo it and it's doing nothing.

Here is my code:

```
public function handlequiz()
{
    $datetime = Date("Y-m-d, h:m:s");

    $parameter = DB::table('parameter')->first();
    $countchoice = $parameter->multiplechoice;

    $customer_answer = new CustomerAnswer;

    for ($i=0; $i <= $countchoice; $i++) 
    { 
        $radio = Input::get('radio'.$i);
        $status = DB::table('quiz_answers')->where('answerid', '=', $radio)->lists('status');

    }

    $answerimplode = implode(";", $status); 

    $customer_answer->email = Input::get('email');
    $customer_answer->cust_id = Input::get('id');
    $customer_answer->multiplechoice = $answerimplode;
    $customer_answer->save();

    return Redirect::to('quiz')->with('message', FlashMessage::DisplayAlert('Your answer has been submitted.', 'info'));
}
```

I tried to vardump `$status` inside for it return me an array so I implode it. But outside `for{}` it returns nothing.

Is there any suggestion to fix this?

Comment: What is the field type of Multiplechoice, I'm just curious. In fact I never saw any case where you could store an Array as Model attribute, if this is some sort of relation to another Model than you might want to see http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: hi!. multiplechoice field type is varchar. it stores customer answer. 

for parameter->multiplechoice its just for knowing how many question. it doesn't have any relationship

Comment: Can you tell us what is the Exception you're having there, as implode always returns a string

Comment: what the exception means?.

i've tried to echo the answerimplode it returns me nothing. 
and i've tried vardump $status it returns me nothing. no errors just blank page. i use die() statement so can ensure that it returns me something.

But if I try to vardump inside for { } I can get the array value.

Comment: Try to concatenate status with it'self like declare status outsite the loop, and than do $status .= "some new value"

Comment: i tried to do some new value at outside for. $status = array('some', 'new') and implode. it give me result some;new like expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop is overwriting the `$status` variable every iteration. Therefore, if the last iteration doesn't find a status value, your `$status` variable will be an empty array, which when imploded, gives you an empty string.

I'm assuming that `quiz_answers.answerid` is supposed to be unique, and you're trying to get the one status for each of the radio selections. If your `quiz_answers` query should only be returning one record per `answerid`, you're probably looking for the `pluck()` method, not the `lists()` method.

```
$status = array();
for ($i=0; $i <= $countchoice; $i++) 
{ 
    $radio = Input::get('radio'.$i);
    // add the 'status' value to the $status array
    // pluck gets the value of the field from the first result, whereas
    // lists would return an array with the value from all the results
    $status[] = DB::table('quiz_answers')->where('answerid', '=', $radio)->pluck('status');
}

// use array_filter to remove any empty values in the $status array
$answerimplode = implode(";", array_filter($status));
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion using pluck I just can get last answer.

Comment: I remove array_filter from what you suggest me. And it works!!. Thanks a lot. I got all the answer.

Comment: Ah, I see. You need the array entry even if it is blank. That makes sense to remove the array_filter, then. Glad it's working.

Answer (score 0):

As optimization, use `whereIn` function

```
radios = array();
for ($i=0; $i <= $countchoice; $i++) 
    $radios[] = Input::get('radio'.$i);

$status = DB::table('quiz_answers')->whereIn('answerid',$radios)->lists('status');
$answerimplode = implode(";", $status);
```